# Need help converting table to longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

How convert the following table to longtable with the same setting. I have problem with enumerate and correct size row and {tabular} not working in longtable

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{scene}
\label{table:econ:programmers}
\begin{tabular}{| >{\raggedright}p{0.20\linewidth} 
          | >{\raggedright}p{0.28\linewidth} 
          | >{\raggedright}p{0.28\linewidth} 
          | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.12\linewidth}|}
 \hline
 question & step & result & yes/no \\
 \hline
 Ask-1 & \begin{enumerate}
        \item[1)] some change 1;
        \item[2)] some change 2;
    \end{enumerate}
     & message & Yes \\

 \hline
 Ask-2 & \begin{enumerate}
        \item[1)] some change 1;
        \item[2)] some change 2;
    \end{enumerate}
     & message & Yes \\

 \hline
 Ask-3 & \begin{enumerate}
        \item[1)] some change 1;
        \item[2)] some change 2;
    \end{enumerate}
     & message & Yes \\

 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

I have many more lines in this table.

Ok, I edited code to longtable, but caption and label not working now.
Error: LaTeX Error: \caption outside float. See code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}
\caption{scene\label{table:econ:programmers}}\\
\begin{longtable}{| >{\raggedright}p{0.20\linewidth} 
              | >{\raggedright}p{0.28\linewidth} 
              | >{\raggedright}p{0.28\linewidth} 
              | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.12\linewidth}|}
\hline
question & step & result & yes/no \\
\hline
Ask-1 & \begin{enumerate}
            \item[1)] some change 1;
            \item[2)] some change 2;
        \end{enumerate}
         & message & Yes \\

\hline
Ask-2 & \begin{enumerate}
            \item[1)] some change 1;
            \item[2)] some change 2;
        \end{enumerate}
         & message & Yes \\

\hline
Ask-3 & \begin{enumerate}
            \item[1)] some change 1;
            \item[2)] some change 2;
        \end{enumerate}
         & message & Yes \\

\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments. What's the problem with `enumerate`?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I edited source code, Thanx

Answer (score 1):

It is best to make examples complete documents that can be tested  but just delete `\begin{table}[ht]` and change `tabular` to `longtable` then move the `\caption` inside `longtable` as a row: `\caption{scene\label{table:econ:programmers}}\\`

Comment: Thanx, I edited code to longtable(see new attach), but caption not working now.

Comment: And second column not correct display position. must be left and top position